# PHP-Based intranet application Call center

Tags: php, c++, voip

As in title, I am making a PHP-Based intranet application Call center, I've finished the DB design/UI. But now I need to automatically intercept calls and send the caller ID to the PHP webserver so the request is routed to the next free agent while his webpage refreshes with the caller's card(and previous questions maybe). Now, How can i route a call inside LAN?, My setup will be a switch where multiple telephone lines is connected this switch is connected with the server where there's a module(Maybe C++ that can intercept calls,route it to free agent,record the call and open the caller's card in the screen of the agent). So, Can any one give me a starting point for this call routing and call intercepting problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [TrixBox](http://www.trixbox.org/)? This should be able to handle incoming calls, and from memory I believe it has methods to send data elsewhere eg to your webserver.  From there it should be able to route the call over an IP-based network to your next free agent.

This obviously depends on the flexibility of your hardware and whether you could integrate this or not...! :-)

Comment: That's perfect, But from what I understood it can only handle incoming calls, I need to be able to make outbound calls too. Also, do you know if a Web-based SIP softphone can be implemented using PHP and AJAX ?

Comment: Trixbox can handle outgoing calls as well - I've not used it personally, but I've seen a working installation used with 4 lines for both incoming and outgoing.  Re your softphone question - no idea, I'm afraid!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/):

> Asterisk is software that turns an ordinary computer into a voice communications server. Asterisk powers IP PBX systems, VoIP gateways, conference servers and more. It is used by small businesses, large businesses, call centers, carriers and governments worldwide. Asterisk is free and open source.

To use it with PHP, have a look at http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+PHP